# Dart project with Dokku. Fails push to master

Tags: git, dart, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm trying to build Dart project with Dokku on DigitalOcean. Doing it in same way as Node.js project. But I'm getting errors when pushing git to Dokku origin. Can you please help me with that:

```
$ git push dokku master 
Counting objects: 632, done. 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (605/605), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (632/632), 7.98 MiB | 74.00 KiB/s, done. 
Total 632 (delta 264), reused 0 (delta 0) 
-----> Building svpe ... 
Dart app detected 
-----> Welcome, this machine is: Linux e82c0d50ae50 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
-----> Installing Dart VM via URL http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/dart-editor-archive-integration/latest/dartsdk-linux-64.tar.gz 
remote: % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current 
remote: Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 
remote: 100 127 100 127 0 0 426 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 494 
remote: 
remote: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format 
remote: tar: Child returned status 1 
remote: tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now 
To dokku@95.85.57.74:svpe 
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) 
error: failed to push some refs to 'dokku@95.85.57.74:svpe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having trouble with the dart-editor-linux tarball. I think its being blocked or you are getting a 404 page since according to the output it seems it didn't download much. Try going into the machine, and doing 'wget http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/dart-editor-archive-integration/latest/dartsdk-linux-64.tar.gz' and see what you get. If its a small file, open it in vim or nano and see if its not some HTML.

I think once you have that diagnosed, it will get you further. Right now its failing to unarchive the file because its not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too! My solution was adding additional swap space to the server. I was using a 512MB DigitalOcean droplet with Dokku.

**Add 512MB swap file**

```
su -
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288
mkswap /swapfile1
chown root:root /swapfile1
chmod 0600 /swapfile1
swapon /swapfile1
```

**Update fstab**

vi /etc/fstab

```
/swapfile1 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Verify with `free -m`

I got the steps from this [page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/)